# How can I release the webcam opened by Opencv in pytq5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pyqt, pyqt5

i want to click a button to start to capture frame and click another button to release the webcam which allows me to redo the process.

but a problem occurs when i run this code below and click the button:

```
import cv2

...
self.StartVideo.clicked.connect(self.startVideo)
...

def startVideo(self):
    self.StartVideo.setDisabled(True)

    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.cap.release()
```

the system crashed and said Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

and then i tried this way:

```
import cv2

...
self.StartVideo.clicked.connect(self.startVideo)
self.StartVideo.clicked.connect(self.closeVideo)
...

def startVideo(self):

    from Video_Analysis.video_threads import video_thread

    self.videoThread = video_thread()
    self.videoThread.start()

def closeVideo(self):
    self.videoThread.stop()
```

Video_Analysis.video_threads.py is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import threading
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
import cv2


class video_thread(QtCore.QThread):
# finishSignal_frame = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
# finishSignal_mark = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(video_thread, self).__init__(parent)
    self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

  def run(self):
    self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
    self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
    self.cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
    while True:
        ret, frame = self.cap.read()
        rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QImage(rgbImage.data, rgbImage.shape[1], rgbImage.shape[0],
                                         QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        convertToQtFormat = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(convertToQtFormat)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(convertToQtFormat)

  def stop(self):
    self.cap.release()
    self.terminate()
```

but the problem is same, how can i sovle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you work my answer?